# user authentication using Google Datastore

Tags: spring-mvc, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am building a web application using spring MVC framework on google app engine platform.

Is it a good idea to build user authentication using Google Cloud Datastore?

To describe more, on every user registration, I store this user's details (email, firstname, lastname, password) as a 'user' entity in datastore. For authentication, I validate login credential with GQL (Google Query Language).

Is there any framework or design pattern for this?

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason the OAuth API (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/  or https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/) won't do the trick?  you wanna keep your OWN registry of users or something?

Comment: Thanks for links, yes, I want to keep my own registry of users.

Comment: I don't think there is a framework for this.  You might want to use the Users API, but that means logging in through gmail accounts, which might not be what you require